# Вывод содержимого файла

Tags: файлы, java

Привет. Как в моем случае вывести содержимое файла?
Вот тут у нас есть значение `myName`:

```
String myName = request.getParameter("text");
```

Вот тут у нас сравнивают параметр `text` с другими именами файлов:

```
for (String string : files) {
if (myName.equals(string)) {
```

Можете помочь сделать так, чтобы если `text` совпадает со `string`, то вывести содержимое файла, которое совпадает с `text`.
Вот целый код(наверняка в нем есть ошибки,если есть помогите исправить):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class servlet extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static List<String> getFileNames(File directory, String extension) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        File[] total = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : total) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(extension)) {
                list.add(file.getName());
            }
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                List<String> tempList = getFileNames(file, extension);
                list.addAll(tempList);          
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException{ 
            request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
            String myName = request.getParameter("text");

            List<String> files = getFileNames(new File("C:\\Users\\vany\\Desktop\\test"), "txt");
            for (String string : files) {
            if (myName.equals(string)) {
                   try {
                        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\vany\\Desktop\\test\\" + string);
                        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
                        int b;
                        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
                        writer.print("<html>");
                        writer.print("<head>");
                        writer.print("<title>HelloWorld</title>");
                        writer.print("<body>");
                        writer.write("<div>");
                        while((b = reader.read()) != -1) {
                            writer.write((char) b);
                        }
                        writer.write("</div>");
                        writer.print("</body>");
                        writer.print("</html>");

                    } 
                   catch (Exception ex) {
                         System.exit(0);
                    }
                }

            }
           }
    }
```

Просто,можете ,пожалуйста,проверить ошибки в коде,а то пока не выводит ничего,и сказать,что куда подставить)
Тут ,по моему,надо что-то с этим:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
System.exit(0);
}
```

И что-то с этим:

```
 FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
```

Может в программе надо что-то местами поменять,или заменить writer.write на writer.print?А и можно как-то код сократить?

Comment: Если кто не понял,надо вывести содержимое файла ,имя которого совпадает с myName.

Comment: Я могу больше кода дать ,как находится string.

Comment: тоесть, вы папку на вход получаете, или как?

Comment: А и обязательно ли пользователю вводить, например hello.txt, чтобы вывести содержимое этого файла или можно писать просто hello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-нибудь так...

```
if (myName.equals(string)) {
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\vany\\Desktop\\test\\" + string);
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        int b;
        while((b = reader.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) b);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

Comment: а вот так будет правильно,и выведется ли это

Comment: writer.print("<div>");
System.out.print((char) b);
writer.print("</div>");

Comment: writer.print((char) b);

Comment: тогда уж

    if (myName.equals(string)) {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\vany\\Desktop\\test\\" + string);
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
            int b;
            writer.write("<div>");
            while((b = reader.read()) != -1) {
                writer.write((char) b);
            }
            writer.write("</div>");
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

А то каждый символ будет в отдельном div'е =)

Comment: А что этот код сделает,а то мне надо вот,что:Вот смотрите,в коде ,который я дал выше,выводятся файлы txt из определенной директории,пользователь ввел что-то,это "что-то",сравнивается с именами выведенных файлов,если совпадает название и ,что ввел пользователь,то вывести имя этого самого файла

Comment: Тот код, что я предложил, выведет содержимое файла, если его имя совпадет с именем, введенным пользователем.

Comment: Просто,можете проверить ошибки в коде,а то пока не выводит ничего.

Answer (score 0):

С catch разобрался надо прописать:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

А в

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
```

Надо потом прописать

```
finally {
  close(reader);
  }
```

Есть ли еще ошибки?